# How can I set up meta tables so inserting large sets of data is efficient?

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance, database-design

I'm working on a survey project and am looking for the best way to keep track of the response data in a relational database. Let's say the survey record people's favorite foods. Later I will add additional data to new foods (calories). I believe that I think the tables should look like this:

**people**

```
id | name
==================
1  | John
2  | Suzy
3  | Joe
4  | Laura
5  | Bob
```

**foods**

```
id  | food       | calories
============================
10  | spaghetti  | 950
11  | meatloaf   | 850
12  | tofu       | 600
13  | cake       | 550
```

**choices**

```
**people_food**
------------------
1   |  10
2   |  11
3   |  12
4   |  13
5   |  10
```

This does a nice job of allowing me to use integers for the connections between tables - that makes doing `JOINs` fast and keeps me from having duplicate data. The downside, I believe, is that prior to inserting new data I must first do an ID lookup on the **foods** table to make sure the food you're adding doesn't already exist.

That's simple enough for a small database, but what if I decided that I would be asking people for their top 100 favorite foods, and this survey was going to be sent out to thousands of people? Even with an index on the **foods** table that means that every time we go to insert the 100 choices we'll need to query **foods** to get the IDs of existing foods. (Does that mean 100 queries? ) I think I might do something like:

```
foreach($response as $food)
{
    $food_id = my_mysql_function('select id from foods where food = "spaghetti"');

    if( ! $food_id ){
      $food_id = my_mysql_function_return_query_id( "insert into foods (NULL, '$food')" );
    }

    my_mysql_function( "insert into people_foods ($person_id, $food_id)" );

}
```

I suppose another would to use the food name as the primary key for the foods table and get rid of the integer, but this seems like bad practice, does not lend itself towards de-duplication, and also slows down queries from what I understand.

**Questions**

With a schema like this, what is the most efficient way to record a new response and either get an ID for an existing food or insert the food? If I am inserting 100 foods I would normally do something like:

```
$existing = my_mysql_function('select id, food from foods where food in ('.implode($response,',').')');
foreach($existing as $food){
   my_mysql_function_return_query_id( "insert into people_foods ($person_id, '$food['id']')" );
   unset($response[$food]);
}

foreach($response as $food){
 //same code as above mentioned earlier in the question
}
```

Or, is there simply another table schema that would be better for doing something like this?

Comment: Who could think of their one hundred favorite foods? Suppose everybody could do this. I can guarantee that most people will have pizza, hamburgers, french fries, etc. on their list so many of the choices may already be in the database. How are you getting the calories? Are you worried about a response time or what?

Comment: Yes - you're right. But regardless of how many favorite foods people can come up the aspect of the question I'm concerned with is how best to optimize data inserts on existing datasets for this type of schema (where you may have a large, unlimited number of "choices"). Thoughts on that part? The calories are there to illustrate a purpose for linked data (so we don't just store everything in a flat table). Finally, response time may be OK but really I want to know if there is a better way than doing so many queries and manipulating the data with PHP between all the inserts.

Comment: Given some sensible indexes the database side of this should perform ok for the load you are sketching. BUT you must be careful to lock the food table from looking into it for a food and inserting it, if it wasn't found. Otherwise two sessions might look for the same food, don't find it and both try to insert it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry about the speed of those selects. Just make sure you have an index on food from the foods table and it should be able store millions of rows before getting one row would be a bottle neck.

Don't fall into the trap of optimizing to soon or to assume that things will be slow. Try first.

I like "real" keys so I would put food as primary key and skip the id but as you say, joining on ints are faster.

Comment: Good points - I hope that it will work fine. What about thoughts on doing `SELECT * FROM foods WHERE food IN ('.implode(',',$list_of_foods).')'` ? If there were 10k rows I think that could take quite a while even if `food` was an indexed column. I seem to recall trying to look up users by e-mail address in this way once and it seemed very slow.

Comment: I think you will save some of the overhead on the connection. You might loose it in the php script as you have to process the results. And don't do * unless you need all columns.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the definitions for `my_mysql_function`, `my_mysql_function_return_query_id`, `$person_id`, and `$response`. This is far from perfect (a pretty dirty solution) and may have bugs as I haven't tested it, but it *should* work more efficiently. I hope this can lead you in the right direction.

```
$existing = my_mysql_function('SELECT id FROM foods WHERE food IN (' . implode($response, ', ') . ')');
foreach($existing as $food) {
    my_mysql_function("INSERT INTO people_foods VALUES ($person_id, $food['id'])");
    unset($response[$food]); // Shouldn't this be $response[SOME_INTEGER]?
}

my_mysql_function('INSERT INTO foods VALUES (NULL, ' . implode($response, ', NULL), (NULL, ') . ', NULL)');
my_mysql_function("INSERT INTO people_foods VALUES ($person_id, (SELECT id FROM foods WHERE food='" . implode($response, "')), ($person_id, (SELECT id FROM foods WHERE food='") . "'))");
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess one of my main concerns is that I still have to look up 100 foods using the `WHERE food IN` clause. Seems like that could be slow. Thoughts?

Comment: The only way I can think of optimizing that part is to perform a batch of queries all in one string. That way, it will make use of the indexed id column. I'm honestly not sure how to benchmark stuff like that so I don't know if that'd be any faster but it certainly makes sense instead. I think using `IN` causes a full table scan. Not 100% on that, though.